# Where-clause based on attribute value in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, iteration, where-clause

I am trying to create a Python toolbox which will iterate through selected features and create a statistics table for each selected feature.

It works as follow:

1. Define parameters, including the input layers with selected features
2. Export selected features in new layer
3. Use `searchCursor()`  to iterate through rows of the new layer
4. Get row value
5. Use row value in an expression to apply `SelectLayerByAttribute()`
6. Use selected feature to clip another input layer
7. Apply some other tools before compute statistics on the other input layer

```py
fc = newLayer
field = "ID_reserve_castor"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
row = cursor.next()

while row:

    value = row.getValue(field)

    # Process: Select Layer By Attribute (Select Layer By Attribute) (management)
    Reserve_castor_ExportFeature = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(
        in_layer_or_view=fc,
        selection_type="NEW_SELECTION",
        where_clause='"ID_reserve_castor" = ' + value,
        invert_where_clause="")

    row = cursor.next()
```

The iteration and `row.getValue()` work, but not the `SelectLayerByAttribute()`.
As the new layer is saved in a geodatabase, I used the exemple mentioned in [esri technical support web page](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011590).

```py
   #Identifies File Geodatabase
    if WPtype == "esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory.1":
        #sample where clause for fgdb data
        WhereClause = '"ObjectID" = ' + value
        print WhereClause
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: Do ***not*** use `arcpy.SearchCursor` for anything. Instead use`arcpy.da.SearchCursor`. If you *must* manage the selection environment of a layer inside a cursor, make sure it doesn't corrupt the layer on which the cursor is already operating. Best practice is to never nest cursors.

Comment: @Vince You are my hero (Foo Fighters tune in my head). I ran into exactly that problem. it was "da" and suddenly I was one step further, where I hang for 3 hours agonizing about my stupid SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Vince arcpy.SearchCursor is a legacy tool, and you should be looking at arcpy.da.SearchCursor (unless you only have access to a really old version of ArcMap).

Another suggestion is to hold off on writing the selected features to a new feature class, because you can use a selection directly in a search query and other tools. Writing to a file generally is a bottleneck in the code, and my preference is to save it to the last step.

An example to get you started:

```
selection = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(fc,"NEW_SELECTION",
        where_clause='"ID_reserve_castor" = ' + value).getoutput(0)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(selection,["SHAPE@"]) as sc:
    for row in sc:
       feature = row[0]
       #you can clip or do something with the shape
```

If the field you are using in the where clause is string/text, you would need to place the value in single quotes. `'"ID_reserve_castor" = ' + "'"+value+"'"` (there is an easier way to do that, but I don't remember if it is available in Python 2.7).